# Using PHP to send http data from browser to another server

Tags: php

Im trying to stream video.mp4 file from a remote server thru a php script on a local server connected to the browser. So it looks like this....

Browser <==http==> [server1 running my.php] <==> [server 2 with VIDEO.MP4 file]

Browser connected to server 1 wants to play video.mp4 located on remote server 2.

User goes on my website (server 1) and wants to play a video. The video is located on server2. The browser calls my.php script on server 1 giving the url to server 2 like this

http://www.server1.com/my.php?url=http://www.server2.com/video.mp4

Im making a php script that accepts the url to the new server, fetches the file from the remote server and sends it back to the browser to be played.

There can be several remote servers, some of them i have no control over.

So my script is below, the script works but it doesnt do progressive downloading that allows the video to start playing immediately while downloading the rest of it, instead the browser waits a long time for the whole large video to download to the browser first (2Gigs), then it starts playing.

I need it to start playing right away while its still downloading, before the whole file is fetched. Another plus would be able to seek forwards and backwards too (maybe asking too much there tho).

Anybody have any ideas how to fix it, or some other alternative i can do?

```
<?php
$url=$_GET["url"];  // URL to remote server that has the video file
$s = fopen($url, "rb");

if (!$s ) {
    echo "open failed";
$url = str_replace("https", "http",$url);
$s = fopen($url, "rb");
    if (!$s) {
        echo "\n<br>FAILED cant open:". $url;
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($http_response_header)) {
    foreach ($http_response_header as $h) {
       header($h);
    }
}
else {
     $type = 'Content-Type:video/mp4';
     header($type);
 }
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

 while (!feof($s)) { // read from other server, send to browser
     echo fread($s, 4096);
 }
 fclose($s);
?>
```

Comment: this may be helpful https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

Comment: Thanks i found the solution!

Comment: would you mind to update your question adding the solution for future readers?

Comment: If you found the solution, you should post an Answer.